# making a new version of lambda function and using existing API make error about route

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I`m really struggling to solve this problem.
if you help me, I really appreciate it during my lifetime.

screen capture

[image: 1]

As you see in the above link,
I made a new version of a lambda function(main function) and
I tried to make a trigger(API gateway) by using the existing API gateway which is already used in the main function

making the trigger is completed but continuously showing the below error message.

"The API with ID vye6oo0qc5 doesn’t include a route with path /main_function having an integration arn:aws:lambda"

Even though I delete the trigger in the main function, the error message still exists.
How could I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice to interact between api gateway and lambda versions is using stages variable and lambda aliases

Or you can try to use Lambda ARN instead of function name on API gateway console